# Testing redux-saga with multiple selects

Tags: jestjs, redux-saga

I have a saga with select functions that should take couple of information from state and use them to go to new url.

CODE FOR SAGA:

```
export function* appRedirectToNewTopic() {
  const getCreatingNewTopicError = yield select(getCreatingTopicError);
  const newTopicId = yield select(getNewTopicId);
  const groupId = yield select(getGroupId);
  if (isEmpty(getCreatingNewTopicError)) { // this is lodash isEmpty
    yield put(push(getRouteUrl(routerUrls.TOPIC_CHAT.url, {
      groupId,
      topicId: newTopicId,
    })));
  } // TODO add here when notification is made
}
```

CODE FOR SAGA TEST:

```
describe('appRedirectToNewTopic', () => {
  const action = appCreateNewTopicFinishedAction();
  const generator =
    cloneableGenerator(appRedirectToNewTopic)(action);
  const expectedGroupId = {
    apiGroups: {
      groupInfo: {
        groupInfo: {
          id: 466,
        },
      },
    },
  };
  const expectedTopicId = {
    apiTopics: {
      newTopicId: 22466,
    },
  };
  let topicId;
  let groupId;

  it('should return empty error', () => {
    expect(generator.next().value)
      .toEqual(select(getCreatingTopicError));
  });

  it('should return new topicId', () => {
    topicId = generator.next(expectedTopicId).value;
    expect(topicId)
      .toEqual(select(getNewTopicId));
  });

  it('should return groupId', () => {
    groupId = generator.next(expectedGroupId).value;
    expect(groupId)
      .toEqual(select(getGroupId));
  });

  it('should redirect user to new topic screen', () => {
    expect(generator.next().value)
      .toEqual(put(push(getRouteUrl(routerUrls.TOPIC_CHAT.url, {
        groupId,
        topicId,
      }))));
  });
});
```

The error that I get is in should redirect user to new topic and the error is `Expected value to equal:
      {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "PUT": {"action": {"payload": {"args": ["/chat/[object Object]/[object Object]"], "method": "push"}, "type": "@@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD"}, "channel": null}}
    Received:
      undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are passing to the next method is what the current `yield` is supposed to yield, not the one you are testing with equal after that. Try this:

```
describe('appRedirectToNewTopic', () => {
  const action = appCreateNewTopicFinishedAction();
  const generator =
    cloneableGenerator(appRedirectToNewTopic)(action);
  const expectedGroupId = {
    apiGroups: {
      groupInfo: {
        groupInfo: {
          id: 466,
        },
      },
    },
  };
  const expectedTopicId = {
    apiTopics: {
      newTopicId: 22466,
    },
  };
  let topicId;
  let groupId;

  it('should return empty error', () => {
    expect(generator.next().value)
      .toEqual(select(getCreatingTopicError));
  });

  it('should return new topicId', () => {
    topicId = generator.next().value;
    expect(topicId)
      .toEqual(select(getNewTopicId));
  });

  it('should return groupId', () => {
    groupId = generator.next(expectedTopicId).value;
    expect(groupId)
      .toEqual(select(getGroupId));
  });

  it('should redirect user to new topic screen', () => {
    expect(generator.next(expectedGroupId).value)
      .toEqual(put(push(getRouteUrl(routerUrls.TOPIC_CHAT.url, {
        groupId,
        topicId,
      }))));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanx Martin. It worked. To be honest, I didn't get it why did it work. Could you explain a bit more your answer or point me to some reading material. sorry I can give you only 25 pints. I would give you more if I could :)

Comment: This is not something specific to sagas, but generators in general. I suggest to just play with generators a bit - you can also read up on them on popular sites like MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: That said I will try to explain the problem further. It is important to keep in mind what part of the generator is executing at which moment. When you create a generator none of the code inside is executed, the first time you call `next` the generator starts executing from the beginning to the first yield. The value you get from first `next()` call is what the first yield yielded. Now when you call `next` second time, you can pass a value to it and it will be used in place of the first yield expression, then the function will continue executing with this new value to the second yield and so on

Comment: Thank you Martin :)